# Return list of string from list nested in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have three classes; State, County, and City.  State contains a list of County.  County contains a list of City.

```
public class State
{
  public string StateCode;
  List<County> Counties;
  List<string> CitiesInState
  {
    get
    {
      return //LINQ STATEMENT TO GET LIST OF ALL CITYNAMES FROM LIST OF COUNTIES 
    }
  }
}

public class County
{
  public string CountyName;
  List<City> Cities;
}

public class City
{
  public string CityName;
}
```

I am trying to return a list of all CityNames within the State.  Since this is a property of an item that is in a List which is an item within another List, I'm not sure it is possible.  I haven't been able to write anything that will even compile.  Is this possible?  Can someone point my in the right direction?

Comment: You should use properties, and collections properties should be readonly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking how to *flatten* a nested list:

```
Counties.SelectMany(c => c.Cities).Select(c => c.CityName)
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you just need:

```
return Counties.SelectMany(county => county.Cities) // IEnumerable<City>
               .Select(city => city.CityName)       // IEnumerable<string>
               .ToList();                           // List<string>
```

[`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in its simplest form) can be seen as a "flattening" operation - each element of the original collection is projected to another collection, and all the elements of all those "sub-collections" are yielded in turn.

See my [Edulinq article on `SelectMany`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/27/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-9-selectmany.aspx) for more details, and information about the other overloads. (One of the other overloads could be used to provide the "city to name" projection within `SelectMany`, but I find this approach more readable.)